# Upload an in memory UIimage to Dropbox in iOS

Tags: ios, upload, stream, uiimage, dropbox

I want to upload an image generated by my app to Dropbox. I see the upload method from DBRestClient, but it seems to me that I have to write the Image to a temp file before calling the upload method.

Is there any way to upload file from an object in memory? Something like this:

```
UIimage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc]....
//
// Here I create the image on my app
//
NSData *myData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 1.0);
DBRestClient *rc = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
self.restClient = rc;
[rc release];
self.restClient.delegate = self;
[self.restClient uploadFile:@"myImage.jpg" toPath:@"DropBoxPath" fromPath:myData];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header of DBRestClient does only reveal

```
/* Uploads a file that will be named filename to the given root/path on the server. It will upload
   the contents of the file at sourcePath */
- (void)uploadFile:(NSString*)filename toPath:(NSString*)path fromPath:(NSString *)sourcePath;
```

The iPhone has a disk, so upload your image as tmp file with the given method and delete it afterwards? You can use [writeToFile:atomically:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-CIAEAHFJ) or [writeToFile:options:error:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-BCIICCHI) of [NSData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for that purpose.

Comment: Hello Nick, Thanks for the answer. I will try this way.  Greetings, Gazolla

Answer (score 3):

That's the way I implemented the solution:

```
- (void) uploadToDropBox {
    self.restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
    self.restClient.delegate = self;
    [self.restClient createFolder:dropBoxFolder];

    NSString *fileName = @"myImage.png"; 
    NSString *tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    NSString *imagePath = [tempDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.loadQRCodeImage.image)];
    [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

    [self.restClient uploadFile:fileName toPath:dropBoxFolder fromPath:imagePath];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian ,Can you help me to upload pdf from url to Dropbox ?